# django tzinfo = utc now found while using datetime and utc

Tags: python, datetime, utc, tzinfo

while performing a test case for my model named Device
I found and error in my terminal the error is

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_device (farm_management.test.test_models.TestDevice)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/admin123/igrow-api/app/farm_management/test/test_models.py", line 68, in test_device
    self.assertEqual(self.device1.last_fetched_on, datetime.datetime.utcnow())
AssertionError: datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 12, 9, 35, 19, 280416, tzinfo=<UTC>) != datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 12, 9, 35, 19, 281136)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.903s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

I think this means I made some mistake while importing the datetime and utc

test file codes are here

```
import datetime

from django.test import TestCase
from django.db.utils import IntegrityError
from farm_management.models import Farm, Device, BatchYield, Batch



class TestDevice(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        self.device1 = Device.objects.create(
            id="C004825",
            fetch_status="1",
            last_fetched_on=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
            geolocation="28.48064,77.09301",
            device_status="inactive",
            is_active="1",



        )

    def test_device(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.device1.id, "C004825")
        self.assertEqual(self.device1.fetch_status, "1")
        self.assertEqual(self.device1.last_fetched_on, datetime.datetime.utcnow())
        self.assertEqual(self.device1.geolocation, "28.48064,77.09301")
        self.assertEqual(self.device1.device_status, "inactive")
        self.assertEqual(self.device1.is_active, "1")
```

I just don't that how can i get the matching output which shows in my terminal and

Comment: can you use aware datetime instead of the naive datetime returned by utcnow; basically `datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)`?

Comment: I tried this method It also shows the error 

AssertionError: datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 12, 10, 28, 29, 167876, tzinfo=<UTC>) != datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 12, 10, 28, 29, 168622, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

Comment: ok seems you need a pytz timezone object; you can try `datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)`.

Comment: Thanks It worked the format is showing correct now but then also there is some error

AssertionError: datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 12, 10, 44, 15, 280685, tzinfo=<UTC>) != datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 12, 10, 44, 15, 281488, tzinfo=<UTC>)

Comment: that's a different problem; if you compare such datetime objects in tests, I'd suggest to ignore the microsecond because chances are very high those are not exactly equal

Comment: how can i ignore them

Comment: e.g. by replacing both with zero; `self.device1.last_fetched_on.replace(microsecond=0)` and `datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc).replace(microsecond=0)`

Comment: I did error again
AssertionError: datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 12, 12, 0, 27, 915197, tzinfo=<UTC>) != datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 12, 12, 0, 27, tzinfo=<UTC>)

Comment: Because microseconds are not zero for the first datetime object. Not sure why without seeing your actual code.

Comment: Hey, It's a request can you please vote up
for this question 
It will help me to earn a badge